# Windows Service: Install fonts

Tags: windows, service, fonts, access-rights

I have a Windows Service which is supposed to install fonts. I have a folder which contains the fonts, and I use this code to install them:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddFontResourceW", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                     string lpFileName);


var fontDestination = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), fontName);

        if (File.Exists(fontDestination))
        {
            return;
        }

        logger.Info(String.Format("Installing font: {0}", fontName));

        try
        {
            File.Copy(fontFullPath, fontDestination);

            // Retrieves font name
            var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
            fontCollection.AddFontFile(fontDestination);
            var actualFontName = fontCollection.Families[0].Name;

            //Add font
            AddFontResource(fontDestination);
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (error == 0)
            {
                //Add registry entry
                logger.Info(String.Format("Font {0} installed successfully", fontName));
                Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts",
                    actualFontName, fontName, RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
```

The font will be copied in the fontDestination(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts)) and then the AddFontResource will add it to the session.

Everything works as expected if I run the service as a console application, or in debug mode. The fonts become available in notepad, word, etc, without restarting the machine.
If I install it and run it as a service, the log confirms that the font is installed successfully, the registry is added, the file is in the Windows/fonts folder, but is not available in Applications that use it(notepad, word, etc)

If I restart my computer I suspect that the windows looks in the registry, sees the file in the Windows/fonts folder and makes it available for apps to use.
**EDIT:** It is actually available after a restart.

I need to run this service on a Virtual machine which will not restart, so I need to font to be available just after installation.

I suspect this has something to do with user rights for services. I specify that the service is logged on as LocalSystem.

Comment: what part of that "I suspect" is suspicion, and what part of it actually happens? The way it's currently phrased suggests that all parts are speculation, so: *are* the fonts available after a restart?

Comment: Yes they are available after a restart, if they are installed from the windows service. If I run the code I posted inside a console app (or run the service as a console app) then they are available without restarting.

Comment: are both run as admin? (i.e. service installed using admin credentials, and the console runs as administrator?)

Comment: I believe you will need to call AddFontResource in the context of the user session(s) as well as in your own.  You can launch a process in a user's session with WTSQueryUserToken and CreateProcessAsUser, a search on those terms should find you some examples.

Comment: Yes, they were both run using administrator rights. @Harry: Yes I figured that out in the mean time. Thanks, but I think the approach is not okay, I will try to install the fonts in a different manner than the service it self, because it creates too much of a overhead. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable or restart the windows service for fonts cache